# JavaScript error in Browser-Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, browser-link

I am working on a project that a former colleague has made. If I run this ASP MVC 4 application in Firefox everything works fine but, when I run it on Internet Explorer 9 I get this weird error:

> [image]

It says there is a error in the SignalR JavaScript Library but I never heard of this. It breaks into a JS file that is not even in the solution.

This SignalR extension is not installed.

**All the references in my views:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/perso.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

I have found the problem, in my console log it breaks on this error:

> TypeError: a[0] is undefined @ browserLink:37

This occurs in my jQuery files. I have updated them with the newest version but no success.

I have no idea how to fix this, any ideas?

Comment: What JavaScript references do you use in your project?

Comment: Updated my question with the JS files I use

Comment: Is `perso.js` referencing some other JS files?

Comment: /// <reference path="jquery-1.7.1.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="knockout-2.1.0.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.5.3.js" />

This is added above. Don't use it tho. Should I remove it?

Comment: The image u shared is of Visual studio. Its nothing with IE9

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I imagine that you're using Visual Studio 2013?  If so, there's a new feature called Browser Link, it's enabled by default.  I just upgraded to VS2013 as well and I'm getting a lot of errors related to Browser Link, when I disable it everything works perfectly.

Here's some more information about Browser Link and how to disable it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

Comment: Another Microsoft special! #BrokenByDesign

Comment: For VS 2017, in the debug toolbar there is a dropdown next to the "Refresh Linked Browsers" button. Click the dropdown and then you'll see the "Enable Browser Link" option.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason, duplication of jQuery file. As you incldued jQuery file twice which cause conflict and jQuery stops working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/perso.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

so replace it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/perso.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I cleaned it up a bit but I still get the error on 2 of the 4 pages. I don't know why.