# Pros Vs Cons of Browser-Link in VS2013

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

My application was getting freeze for 15secs when it loads first time. I look into firebug and it shows Browser-Link. So I search, and found [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187554/javascript-error-in-browser-link) post. I uncheck option of "**Enable Browser Link**" and my application works perfectly. I what are the pros and cons of removing Browser-Link? **If I uncheck it, Would it stop application working as cross browser application**? Pls help I'm new in VS2013.

**Note: My application must run on any device or browser...**

[image: BROWSER LINK ISSUE]

Comment: Browser-Link is a tool that can speed up development (or in your case slow it down), and has no influence on the final application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a msdn blog what browserlink can do:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx

So it help you with the development. You can refresh all your browser tabs (which have the application open at once).
Also you get some live reload features when changing your css for example.

If you install the Visual Studip WebEssentials plugin you get tons of nice browserlink features. See the list here: http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink

You can inspect for example a dom element from your browser and web essentials will open the right Razor View. So it is really just a development thingy and has nothing todo with cross browser compatibility.